# whats wrong with my code to simulate a squash game?

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate the scoring of a squash game using english rules.
These are:

- Only the server is awarded a point if they win a rally.
- If the server wins a rally, they receive a point and continue as server.
- If the returner wins a rally, they become the server but don’t receive a point.
- The ﬁrst player to reach 9 points wins the game unless the score has reached 8-8.
- If the score reaches 8-8, the player who reached 8 ﬁrst decides whether to play to 9 or to 10.

The code I have is this:

```
import random

def eng_game(a,b):
    A = 'bob'
    B = 'susie'
    players = [A, B]

    server = random.choice(players)
    print server

    points_bob = 0
    points_susie= 0

    prob_A_wins = 0.4
    prob_B_wins = 0.6

    while points_bob or points_susie < 9:
        probability = random.random()
        print probability
        if probability < prob_A_wins and server == A:
            points_bob += 1
        elif probability < prob_A_wins and server == B:
            server == A
            print server

        if probability > prob_A_wins and server == B:
            points_susie += 1
        elif probability > prob_A_wins and server == A:
            server == B
            print server

        print points_bob
        print points_susie
```

This code returns that Susie wins 9-0 when in some cases the server should be swapped to Bob to win the point, but this doesn't happen. The serve stays with Susie and she wins the point.

Comment: A description of what your code is doing wrong (or if its giving an error or exception) would be helpful.

Comment: oh yeah sorry ill edit it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is the statements `server == A` and `server == B` should be `server = A` and `server = B` so that assignment takes place instead of a comparison.

Another edge case bug I see is if probability ends up exactly 0.4 your program will act like that virtual serve never took place.

I would change your loop to:

```
while points_bob < 9 and points_susie < 9:
    probability = random.random()
    print probability
    if probability <= prob_A_wins and server == A:
        points_bob += 1
    elif probability <= prob_A_wins and server == B:
        server = A
        print server

    if probability > prob_A_wins and server == B:
        points_susie += 1
    elif probability > prob_A_wins and server == A:
        server = B
        print server

    print points_bob
    print points_susie
```

Comment: if i take out one = sign and just leave one it says that there is an invalid syntax

Comment: I put a corrected version of your while loop in my answer.  I'm guessing you were changing the wrong line.

Comment: it works now in the sense that the serve is being swapped and bob is winning points but it seems to run for an endless time until i restart the shell, it doesnt stop when someone reaches 9 points

Comment: Ah, yeah...  the while loop has a bug in its condition. `while points_bob or points_susie < 9:` is effectively `while (points_bob) or (points_susie < 9):`, so as soon as bob gets a point, `points_bob` is true and you effectively have an infinite loop.  I updated my version of the code.

Comment: Thank you soo much, it working now. You dont know how much i appreciate this, i have been stuck on this all day

Comment: @JoeDay Heh, nice ninja edit - I'm too slow at typing in the mornings apparently... :)

Comment: @Blair sorry, I didn't notice the while loop until the OP complained about the infinite loop

Comment: @JoeDay No need to apologise. It took me a while to notice the infinite loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your loop condition

```
while points_bob or points_susie < 9:
```

is not doing what you think. When interpreted as booleans, numbers are `False` if they are zero and `True` otherwise, meaning this will actually check `(points_bob != 0) or (points_susie < 9)`. This will only be `False` (i.e., the loop will only stop) when Susie has at least 9 points and Bob has no points - if Bob gets any points, the game will go on forever.

To fix this, you should switch to an `and` condition. This will only continue while both players have less than nine points, or to put it another way, it will stop as soon as somebody reaches nine. Therefore, your loop condition should be

```
while points_bob < 9 and points_susie < 9:
```

If you want to change the winning condition to 10 points, then you'll need to compare the player's points to a variable rather than a constant, and then change the variable as needed:

```
winning_score = 9
while points_bob < winning_score and points_susie < winning_score:
    # ...
    # Accumulate your points etc.
    # ...

    # Now need to reach ten points to win.
    winning_score = 10
```

Comment: Beaten to the answer by @JoeDay's edit while I was typing, but I'll leave this up for the example of how to change the winning score.

Comment: Thank you for your answer aswell but i think i will go with the first answer